# Do all Cellular Automata have some kind of information boundary? Can all Cellular Automata be modelled with the Bekenstein Bound?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory, cellular-automata, physics

Since they are discrete models, do they have some kind of information boundary? Can all Cellular Automata models be related to the Bekenstein Bound?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound